# Is there on Ubuntu a best way to execute a program than terminal command "./"

Tags: command-line, executable

Is there on Ubuntu an best way to execute an program than terminal command "./".

I have put PhpStorm into an folder and when I want execute PhpStorm, I must `cd bin/` and execute with this command: "./phpstorm.sh". I think that not the official and best way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`./` is not a command. It's a directory (current directory). This just means that you run a file `./phpstorm.sh` (file named `phpstorm.sh` that is in the current directory). Every command that you write is first searched in all the directories in `$PATH` environment variable. This is why, for instance, `ls` works and you don't have to write `/bin/ls`. Write

```
echo "$PATH"
```

to see what directories are searched.

`/bin` should already be in your `PATH`, so `phpstorm.sh` should always work, no matter in which directory you are (no `./`). However, if you want to run commands from any current directory, then you add `.` (current directory) to the existing path. Usually by putting

```
export PATH=".:$PATH"
```

in your `.profile` file. This is not default but I always do it (if you write any scripts or applications by yourself, it's very inconvenient to always specify current directory directly). However, don't do it for root, it's a bit too powerful and you may break something by mistake.

The other "special" directory is `..` which refers to the parent directory. This is why `cd ..` goes "up". `cd .` wouldn't do anything because you are already there.

Comment: I have found, It's simply in `usr/local/bin`, the launcher "pstorm" launch in an empty folder and I just change the path of launcher. Thank you for you help !

Comment: User-made scripts that need to be accessible system-wide belong in `/usr/local/bin` (you should let `/usr/bin` be managed exclusively by the package manager, otherwise you no longer know what's yours and what isn't, and there may be collisions). Scripts that are meant to be called locally within the needs of a single project should stay in their directory.

Comment: Wherever this script is, if you want to call it, either use it's full path `/wherever/it/is/phpstorm.sh`, or create a symbolic link to `/usr/local/bin` so that it is found in the `$PATH`. This is the accepted way of doing this. When you create a link, you may also skip `.sh` so that you can just say `phpstorm`.

Comment: Putting `.` in front of the `$PATH` is really a bad idea and a potential security hole for any user, not just for root, as just changing to some arbitrary directory (e.g. `/tmp`) can change a standard command. Moreover this should never be necessary. If put in `$PATH`, `.` should always be at the end.

Comment: In general I agree it's a security risk, I won't argue with that (and yes it should probably be at the end). However a sane user will never create executable files with names equal to system tools (unless this is a desired result). When you are working in a project directory where most of the commands ever called are tens of different local scripts with various arguments, it gets *really* annoying having to constantly type `./`, especially as it is a really inconvenient key combination on non-english keyboard layouts. First two letters + TAB is much easier.

Comment: @orion A sane user won't normally create executable files with the same name as a standard tool, but everyone can make mistakes, and not everyone knows *all* these commands. Such files could also be created by other (malicious or not) users. Having `.` at the end of `$PATH` is normally sufficient to avoid typing `./` (but I wish the system could ignore `.` in `$PATH` for *unsafe* directories, such as not owned by the user).

Answer (score 0):

There is no official and best way on Linux, but you can make your life easier (or at least have it involve with less typing) by copying the script to a directory in your $PATH, e.g. `/usr/local/bin` if that directory is in your path. Use `echo $PATH` to see the list of directories the shell searches through to find commands

If the script is written in a way that it assumes the rest of the files are relative to the place it itself is stored, you should add the line

```
cd <original_directory_where_the_script_was_located>
```

as one of the first lines (but at least below the first line starting with `#!`)

If there is no (other) executable called `phpstorm` you might even strip off the `.sh` and just start the program from anywhere by using:

```
phpstorm
```

from the commandline.